# wget and curl stop very quickly and failed to download a file?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wget, curl

I am trying to download https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/spark/spark-2.4.4/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz

which is the latest spark version.

when I tried

`wget https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/spark/spark-2.4.4/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz`

I get

```
spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2     [  <=>                        ]  29.61K   140KB/s    in 0.2s

2019-10-09 11:11:08 (140 KB/s) - 'spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz’ saved [30322]
```

and when I do `curl -O url` I get

```
-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 30322    0 30322    0     0  28075      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:-- 28075
```

then it stops.

I am at a loss on how to diagnose this further? I am noob to Linux and I am Ubuntu with the following info

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

Comment: Adding a `-v` parameter to either `curl` or `wget` commands will show you that what you download has the `text/html` MIME-type, so a first reflex would be to try that URL in your browser...

Comment: Would accept as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a -v parameter to either curl or wget commands will show you that what you download has the text/html MIME-type, so a first reflex would be to try that URL in your browser...

Answer (score 0):

The download link on the website is wrong.

You should download it here: https://www.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-2.4.4/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz

You can verify it with the checksums on: https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html